# Telerik MVC Grid Error 404 when inside PartialView

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I'm having a problem with a mvc grid after deploying to the server.

My grid:

```
Html.Telerik().Grid(Of PortalColaborador.DisciplinasViewModel)() _
            .Name("GridDisciplinas") _
            .DataKeys(Sub(k)
                              k.Add("idPedidoDocumentacao")
                              k.Add("idLDisciplina").RouteKey("idLDisciplina")
                      End Sub) _
            .Columns(Sub(column)
                             column.Bound(Function(item) item.idPedidoDocumentacao).Visible(False)
                             column.Bound(Function(item) item.descricao).Width("80%").Title("Descrição")
                     End Sub) _
            .Editable(Function(e) e.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine)) _
            .DataBinding(Function(dtb) dtb.Ajax().Select("BindDisciplinas", "Disciplinas", New With {.idPedidoDocumentacao = Model.idPedidoDocumentacao})).Render()
```

is inside a partialView (`ListaDisciplinas`) that is inside of another partialView(`detalheEstatuto`).

I'm rendering the Partial like this

```
Html.RenderAction("ListaDisciplinas", "Disciplinas", Model)
```

and i Register the telerik scripts in my layout page.

When testing this on my machine it works fine but after deploying to a server i start to get the **Error 404** when the grid tries to get the data on `BindDisciplinas`.
If instead of rendering the partial view I copy the grid directly to `detalheEstatuto` it works fine even on the server.

Is there any limitation on depth of partial views?

Answer (score 0):

Since i didn't actually need another model on the second partial (`ListaDisciplinas`) i used `Html.Partial("listaDocumentacaoAnexa", Model)` instead, and everything works fine but i dodn't understand why this happens. Any thoughts?